# how can i use visual studio 2008 created dll in visual studio 2010?

Tags: windows, dll, mfc

Get me details which is dynamic link library version used in which are operating

is it possible,  i have created dll in visual studio 2008 and i used this dll in visual studio 2010.

and vice versa  also

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Standard DLL and if you just Exchange plain pointer and PODs and don't use any CRT objects accross the modules you can use any DLL of any Visual Studio Version up and down.

If you try to Exchange std::string objects or elements form the STL, or you try to allocate Memory in the DLL and free it in the EXE you run into troubles. Or if you export classes (not plain interfaces), you may get problems too.

For example. If you create a Standard DLL with the application wizard in VS you get a DLL that is usable from any other module created with any other VS... this will work always.
Again: It just depends on the interface of your functions you are using.